# Open separate terminal logs/output for all services - Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am running a web app with docker-compose with a React frontend and FastAPI (Python) backend.

I am trying to get the output for both services on different terminals (they are currently outputting to the same terminal), are there any changes I can make to docker-compose.yml to achieve this?

Docker Compose File:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  dockerengine:
    build: ./backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend/src:/src
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    network_mode: host
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true  
  
  dockerui:
    build: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/src:/src
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    network_mode: host
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Image showing both services outputting to the same terminal:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open couple of terminals and enter the logs command:

```bash
docker-compose logs -f service_name
```

In your case:

```bash
# in a terminal
docker-compose logs -f dockerengine
# in another terminal
docker-compose logs -f dockerui
```

Comment: It works, I had to use
```docker logs -f {my_container_id}```