# can docker compose with various services enable terminal interaction with a specific service?

Tags: docker-compose, create-react-app

### I know I can use two diffents terminals. [Here is the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73234162/open-separate-terminal-logs-output-for-all-services-docker-compose)

I have a create-react-app project, and I want run

```
sudo docker compose up
```

And I want interact with **test** service via terminal, Jest give me some options like **a** to run all tests or **p** to filter some files.

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  test:
    image: 'node'
    working_dir: '/app'
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    entrypoint: 'npm test'
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    tty: true        # docker run -t
  dev:
    image: 'node'
    working_dir: '/app'
    volumes:
     - ./:/app
    entrypoint: 'npm start'
```

---

When I run

```
sudo docker compose up
```

I can't interact with **test** service.

When I run

```
sudo docker compose run --rm test
```

I can interact with jest.

## There is any way to use only one terminal and interact directly with test service?

Comment: have you tried with `docker compose exec` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_exec/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is any way to use only one terminal and interact directly with test service?

No, not in the way you probably expect.

`docker-compose up` is intended for starting the whole project with all its services. Running it in the foreground will output the logs of all started containers.
In no case will `docker-compose up` connect you directly to one of the containers.

Instead, use `docker-compose run` to start a one-off container or `docker-compose exec` to connect to a running service.

So, to start the project and connect to the `test` container using one terminal you could do

```bash
docker compose up -d # start the services in the background
docker compose run --rm test
```

---

Knowing this, you can now further optimize your `docker-compose.yml` for this:

- drop `stdin_open` and `tty` since these will be automatically set when using `docker-compose run` / `docker-compose exec`
- use [service profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) so the `test` service is not automatically started by default but only when using `docker-compose run` to start it explicitly - and interactively
- if `test` needs the `dev` service to be running add a `depends_on` so it will be started automatically whenever `test` is started

```yaml
services:
  test:
    image: 'node'
    working_dir: '/app'
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    entrypoint: 'npm test'
    depends_on:
      - dev # start `dev` whenever `test` is started
    profiles:
      - cli-only # start `test` only when specified explicitly
  dev:
    image: 'node'
    working_dir: '/app'
    volumes:
     - ./:/app
    entrypoint: 'npm start'
```

With this you can simply run

```bash
docker compose run --rm test
```

to start an interactive terminal connected to `test`. The `dev` service will be started automatically if it is not already running - so basically the same as above but without prior `docker-compose up -d`.

On the other hand, running

```bash
docker compose up
```

would now only start the `dev` service.